# ruby script to insert data in a particular column

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script in which I am able to insert row data in an excel file using the "spreadsheet" gem. I want to alter this and insert data in columns and not the entire row at once in one column.

Sample

> sheet1.row(rowIndex).push "#{data1} \t #{data2} \t #{data3} \t #{data4} \t #{data5}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [guide](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md) you can do this:

> To insert a new row:

`sheet.row(index).push('Column 1', 'Column 2')`

> To alter a row use:

```
sheet.row(index).replace['Column 1', 'Column 2']
```